# Unable to add text file to path in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape some data using BeautifulSoup on python from a site which has some products and then store it in text files in separate folders. Here in the given code I am stuck nearing the end of the same. I have added the rest just as a reference.

```
import unittest, time, random
import urllib.request
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidArgumentException
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

links = []
soup_list = []
imgs = []
website = "https://www.energystar.gov/productfinder"

rate = [i/10 for i in range(10)]
cnt = 0

quote = '"'
newline = '\n'
colon = ' : '


browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\abc\\.wdm\\drivers\\geckodriver\\win64\\v0.29.1\\geckodriver.exe")

url2 = 'https://www.energystar.gov/productfinder/product/certified-room-air-cleaners/results?page_number='
def getdata(url):
    browser.get(url)
    content = browser.page_source
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    return soup1

#pagenos = ['0','13']
pagenos = []
for i in range(0,2):
    pagenos.append(i)
    i =+ 1
print(pagenos)

for i in range(0,len(pagenos)):
    url = url2 + str(pagenos[i])
    soup1 = getdata(url)
    soup_list.append(soup1)
    for main in soup1.findAll('div', attrs = {'class' : 'row certified-room-air-cleaners'}):
        name=main.find('a', href=True)
        if (name != ''):
            links.append((name.get('href')).strip())      

print("Got links : ", len(links))
print("Got soups : ", len(soup_list))
#print('Soup 1:', soup_list[1])

for link in links:
    
    #just for testing 10 links
    cnt = cnt + 1
    if cnt >= 20:
        break
    
    # time delay before we access the next page..
    time.sleep(random.choice(rate))

    #print("Fetching link..... : ", link)
    link = link[5:]
    #print("Fetching link..... : ", link)
    link = website + link
    browser.get(link)
    linkcontent = browser.page_source
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(linkcontent, "html.parser")

    pmname = soup2.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'l-wrapper'}).find('h1')
    if not pmname:
        print("Error no product name for link : ", link)
        continue
    pmname = pmname.text.strip().split(' - ')
    bname = pmname[0].strip()
    mname = pmname[1].strip()
    #print(bname)
    #print(mname)
    
    # Creating folder with Brand Name as name
    try:
        os.makedirs(str(bname))
    except FileExistsError:
        # directory already exists
        pass
    
    # Creating text folders with model number as name
    
    fname = mname + '.txt'
    path = '/' + str(bname)
    a = os.path.join(path, fname)
    print(a)
    ff = open(fname, mode='w')
    ff.write("BRAND NAME : " + quote + bname + quote + newline)
    ff.write("MODEL : " + quote + mname + quote + newline)
    

browser.close()
exit()
```

Here I can successfully create the text file but cant seem to add it the the created path.

Comment: Maybe because of not closing the file. I suggest using `with open` to work with file

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something:

If you are adding anything in list then you must have in write mode to write file but you want to append in exist data then file open must have "a" mode to append data at end and before to write any data inside file. file must be open first then close at end of file to close process of file after finish.